# Facebook Audience Network - NativeAdsManager with AdListener

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-audience-network

I'm using Facebook Audience Network 4.14.1 for Android and trying to perform a logic on my app after the user clicks an ad from Facebook. I was using the version 4.11.x and AdListener was working very well. For some reason, after some versions it's not working anymore. Is there a different way to use that?
After load an ad, I just register a Listener like this:

```
nativeAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {
        // my logic
    }
});
```

Comment: do you mean the code inside `onAdClicked` never gets triggered when you click the ad? have you called `registerViewForInteraction` for your native ad?

Comment: Exactly, `onAdClicked` never gets triggered. I call `registerViewForInteraction` one line of code before set the AdListener. The click on the ad is working well.

Comment: Version 4.11.x works very well, after 4.12.x it doesn't fire the method `onAdClicked`

Answer (score 1):

Have the same issue, seems like this is an acknowledged bug in Facebook's SDK:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/158853171214759/

The latest response from a Facebook employee was:

> After investigating this with the engineering teams, we've decided not
>   to release a fix for this specific issue at this time. However, we
>   have some planned changes that should mitigate this issue in future
>   versions of the SDK.

Thanks, Facebook.

**UPDATE**

I was able to workaround it by creating a custom FrameLayout that detects clicks on it, it's hacky, and not perfect, but better then nothing.

```
public class AdContainer extends FrameLayout implements OnGestureListener {

    GestureDetector clickDetector;
    private NativeAd ad;
    private AdListener listener;

    public AdContainer(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public AdContainer(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public AdContainer(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, @AttrRes int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    @TargetApi(VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public AdContainer(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, @AttrRes int defStyleAttr, @StyleRes int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        clickDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(), this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        clickDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    public void setAd(NativeAd ad, AdListener listener) {
        this.ad = ad;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    // OnGestureListener

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.d("AdContainer", "detected a click in an ad container: " + ad);
        if ((ad != null) && (listener != null)) {
            listener.onAdClicked(ad);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Use it like this:
**(1)** Inflate your ad layout into the new container class:

```
<com.example.AdContainer
    android:id="@+id/ad_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**(2)** When binding your ad to the layout, register it with the `AdContainer`:

```
AdContainer container = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.ad_container);
container.setAd(ad, this); // make sure the current class implements AdListener
```

Comment: Same answer from Facebook almost a year ago. Tks for the workaround.